# virtualenv --relocatable not working on mac

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv, and, due to the release environment (over which I have **NO** control) I need to be able to make it relocatable.

When I make a venv, and then run with --relocatable, it changes a bunch of files, but it maintains:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/brianp/work/tmpy/venv_mac"
```

which seems to destroy the point of relocatable.

When I copy the virtualenv to a new location, and activate, `which python` still points to the original location, or on a different system where the original location doesn't exist, it points to /usr/local/bin.

Is this a bug in virtualenv? or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have at the moment, is

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
VIRTUAL_ENV="$( dirname "$DIR" )"
```

instead of the hard coded virtual_env definition.

However, this involves me manually editing the activate script, which makes me nervous, should I need to do this again...